# How exactly does counter semaphores with pthreads work?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I've been working with pthreads and forks for a while and I got an idea of how threads works, also mutex, conditionals, barriers and binary semaphores, but I haven't be able to grasp the concept of counter semaphores or how they work.

What I understand is that each process enters the wait and a counter decrements and in the signal it increments but I don't understand what this means for the process and how it differs from a binary semaphore. I've read about it and tried watching videos but haven't been able to really understand it.

So I was wondering if someone can explain it in an more understandable way how this works or got any links where they explain it in a clearer way. Any other information or links about multithreading would also be appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online on how semaphores work, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The main difference is how many are allowed in critical section. With a binary semaphore only one.

Comment: Yeah I mean like with counter semaphores how the wait and signal work for multiple threads. And I've tried to read the resources but still not able to understand it completely so I was hoping someone could explain it in an easier way

Comment: Hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/nptl/sem_wait.c

Comment: Does that mean that multiple process can go inside the same lock? wouldn't that cause a race condition

Comment: To avoid race condition stick to a binary semaphore. However, if you want to have X readers only, then you can initialized a semaphore with value = X.

Comment: Oh ok so counter semaphores can only be used with readers? And if I must modify some value inside the critical condition add a mutex there? I guess that would make sense kind of.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following buffer handling:

```
struct buf {
     Mutex lock;
     int   head, tail, n;
     char  *data;
};
int get(Buf *b) {
    lock(&b->lock);
    if (b->head != b->tail) { /* buffer not empty */
        int ret = b->data[b->tail] & 0xff;
        b->tail = (b->tail + 1) % b->n;
        unlock(&b->lock);
        return ret;
     } else {
        /* do what?  if I drop the lock, how do I know when to try again */
     }
}
```

So, we add a semaphore:

```
struct buf {
     Mutex lock;
     Sem   navail, room;
     int   head, tail, n;
     char  *data;
};

int get(Buf *b) {
    int ret;
    SemWait(&b->navail); /* now there will be one! */
    lock(&b->lock);
    assert(b->head != b->tail);
    ret = b->data[b->tail] & 0xff;
    b->tail = (b->tail + 1) % b->n;
    SemPost(&b->room);  /* now there is space */
    unlock(&b->lock);
    return ret;
}
int put(Buf *b, int c) {
    int next;
    SemWait(&b->room); /* now there will be one! */
    lock(&b->lock);
    next = (b->head + 1) % b->n;
    assert(next != b->tail);
    b->data[next] = c;
    b->head = next;
    SemPost(&b->navail);  /* now there is data */
    unlock(&b->lock);
    return ret;
}
```

So, in this example, the mutex protects concurrent updates of the buffer, head and tail; and the semaphores provide a sort of flow control; limiting the number of getters and putters to the data and space available.

As with all things concurrent, there are dozens of different ways and mechanisms to solve concurrent buffer access, this is but one.

What would you initialize *navail* and *room* to?

Comment: I dont know, what I understand of this is that the threads would be going in until they reach the room or navail value and then until one does a signal the next one will go in, but wouldn't the lock already only allow that one thread can go in? So why not use a binary semaphore in the first please or just the lock itself?

Comment: The lock won't work, because you need somebody to unlock it, and only the owner of the lock can unlock it.   The buffering permits handling bursty behavior without backing up; a binary semaphore would only work for a buffer length of 1.  When the buffer is full, the producer behaves as if it were a binary semaphore; when the buffer is empty, the consumer behaves as if it were a binary semaphore; any other point behaves as you would expect from buffering.   Easiest thing to do is cut + paste it into a program, and try for various buffer sizes, and numbers of getters and putters.

Comment: ps: the initial value of navail is zero -- there is no data; and room is n-1.  Since it knows the queue cannot overflow or underflow, if you remove the asserts, room can be set to n.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at a semaphore like a atomic (will explain this term) unsigned integer.
as in it has either a 0 or a positive value, each time a process or a thread waits on a semaphore if the semaphore has a value it will decrement it, if not it will get blocked but don't actively check for a value (which makes it more resource efficient in runtime)
until a there will be a value.
so as long as there is a non 0 value for the semaphore the wait won't block.
the term atomic refers to a value that is safe to work with in a multithreaded/processed environment.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get it so the process go in until the counter reaches 0 then until a process gets out and increase the counter no other process can go back in? What confuses me about this is that this means there are multiple threads inside the same critical section so wouldnt that create a race condition? And if I add mutex inside wouldnt to prevent it, wouldn't this defeat the purpose of a counter semaphore?

Comment: it's more like a block for a resource and not a critical section protector, if let's say 2 threads are waiting on a semaphore and another thread increments it's value, only one of the 2 that have waited will be able to decrement.
it's not suppose to act like a mutex where it protects a critical section, more like a resource management mechanism, where the code continues executing after a wait only if the semaphore has a positive value.
so this way you control how many processes/threads get to run with the value of the semaphore.